# Background music: service, static wrapper, threaded?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-mediaplayer

There seem to be at least two options to implement background music in an app, namely, a service and a static wrapper for MediaPlayer.

For the music service, there is this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

For the wrapper:

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

The first is more complex and, therefore, less desirable in principle.

Could those experienced with background music explain which method is best and why? Also, should the music be played in its own thread, particularly in the case of the wrapper?

Thank you, good folk.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think using a `Service` is more complex. There might be more code and various other aspects you need to take into consideration but the link you provided gives you everything you need. A `Service` will survive orientation changes and you can even leave your app and the music will continue (if you want it to). Also, you'll learn a lot about the `Service` class - how to start, stop, bind, unbind. A useful learning experience.

Comment: I have implemented both already. They work. But a service is clearly more complex since, for one, it requires... a service. I get that with a service, the music will play after the app is closed but this is not a useful feature to me. So, which approach is best for, say, a simple game?

Comment: Whatever works best for you. Personally I'd stick with the `Service` but then again I uses services in my apps regularly. There's no right answer. BTW in answer to the thread aspect - `MediaPlayer` handles its own threading.

Comment: Squonk's pretty much nailed it. Static objects and singletons are overused and generally considered bad design (awkward to test or untestable, cheap way to create globals... which are also bad, etc., etc.), so my two cents is to go with the `Service`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you both. The question now is, bad design aside, is there a performance downside to the wrapper?